# Can I create a single file that mentions all files I want to build : c++

Tags: c++, cmake

In React, I can write code like this for my containers/components:

```
export App from './App/App';
export Chat from './Chat/Chat';
export Home from './Home/Home';
```

This allows me to specify the stuff that I am exporting from that dir. Can I do something like that in `CMake`?

What I want is to be able to create a header file that includes the files that I want to build. I dont want to list them out in `CMakeLists.txt` as it becomes too cluttered. I also dont want to `GLOB_RECURSE` as it doesnt allow me to select files. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create file which lists sources:

**sources.list**:

```
foo.c
bar/baz.c
```

and read it using `file(STRINGS)` command into the variable:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Load list of sources into 'sources' variable
file(STRINGS "sources.list" sources)

# Use the variable
add_executable(my_exe ${sources})
```

---

As pointed by @wasthishelpful, a file used in `file(STRINGS)` **is not tracked** by CMake. That is, if content of the file will be modified(e.g., new sources will be added), explicit `cmake` call is needed to reflect this modification. (That is, simple `make` doesn't cause `cmake` to rerun).

Alternative to `file(STRINGS)`, which force CMake to track file with sources. is `include()`:

**sources.cmake**:

```
set(sources
    "foo.c"
    "bar/baz.c"
)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Run additional script, which fills 'sources' variable with list of sources
include(sources.cmake)

# Use the variable
add_executable(my_exe ${sources})
```

Such a way, if "sources.cmake" will be changed, `cmake` will be **automatically** rerun on `make` call.

Comment: Does this method have the same drawbacks than using GLOB to collect a list of source files? I mean if the file listing the sources is modified, will CMake be aware of the update and regenerate?

Comment: Nice catch: No, if source listing will be modified, CMake *doesn't detect that automatically*. I have added notes about this in the answer, and have added an alternative - `include()` -  which doesn't suffer from that problem.